# Mysql get date interval from year and weekNumber

Tags: mysql, datetime, sequelize.js

I have a table that has fields `year`, `week_number`, `stock_count`. How will I get all rows that fall within a given date range given `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: Week numbers have several modes. Please read this then [edit] your question to tell us which mode -- which variety of week number -- your app uses. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below assumes that the `start_date` is `2020-02-28` and `end_date` is `2021-01-31`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `your_table_name`
WHERE (
        `year` > YEAR('2020-02-28') OR 
        (`year` = YEAR('2020-02-28') AND `week_number` >= WEEK('2020-02-28'))
    ) AND (
        `year` < YEAR('2021-01-31') OR 
        (`year` = YEAR('2021-01-31') AND `week_number` <= WEEK('2021-01-31'))
    )
```

Comment: Works perfect. +1 for ``year` > YEAR('2020-02-28') OR` my code was missing this! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If your table does not have  `date` field, you can not use `start/end_date`. => this would be the "normal" option.

In your case, (I presume this is what you want), you can only extract the `year` and `week` from the start/end_date and only then run a query.

`SELECT WEEK('2020-05-18');` will return the week corresponding to that date

`SELECT YEAR('2020-08-28');` will extract the year from your date

Then you can run your query based on the `year` and `week`.

I hope it makes sense...